# Firebase database how to create list from nodes like WhatsApp Chats page

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am trying to create chat app with Firebase database. I'm reading docs and watching tutorials but there is one thing I could not figure out how to do. When user sends message to another user, creating a chat room with key:  **"senderUserId_receiverUserId"**
 You can see my structure below.

```
{
  "chat_rooms" : {
    "nTAHqCTmLRcLOM8CTfnHF4lRjLf2_oTLYaHMOMibh3ZqOcmpcWDtSCKp1" : {
      "-KtQEGK38lhZrgnNxmqb" : {
        "date" : "07/09/2017 10:28",
        "message" : “Thanks for helping !”,
        "photoUrl" : "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/B/R/Y/m/P/e/blank-profile-hi.png",
        "receiverName" : "Ali”,
        "receiverUid" : "oTLYaHMOMibh3ZqOcmpcWDtSCKp1",
        "senderName" : “John”,
        "senderUid" : "nTAHqCTmLRcLOM8CTfnHF4lRjLf2"
      },
      "-KtQEKK2BmIMzwruN-21" : {
        "date" : "07/09/2017 10:28",
        "message" : “Another Test Message“,
        "photoUrl" : "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/B/R/Y/m/P/e/blank-profile-hi.png",
        "receiverName" : “John”,
        "receiverUid" : "nTAHqCTmLRcLOM8CTfnHF4lRjLf2",
        "senderName" : "Ali",
        "senderUid" : "oTLYaHMOMibh3ZqOcmpcWDtSCKp1"
      },
      "-KtQIGDk5zE4JZuE9pIQ" : {
        "date" : "07/09/2017 10:45",
        "message" : “Test message !“,
        "photoUrl" : "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/B/R/Y/m/P/e/blank-profile-hi.png",
        "receiverName" : “John”,
        "receiverUid" : "nTAHqCTmLRcLOM8CTfnHF4lRjLf2",
        "senderName" : "Ali",
        "senderUid" : "oTLYaHMOMibh3ZqOcmpcWDtSCKp1"
      }
    }
  },
  "users" : {
    "nTAHqCTmLRcLOM8CTfnHF4lRjLf2" : {
      "address" : “istanbul”,
      "cell_phone" : “none”,
      "email" : “john@gmail.com",
      "home_phone" : “none”,
      "name" : “John”,
      "photoUrl" : "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/B/R/Y/m/P/e/blank-profile-hi.png",
      "userId" : "nTAHqCTmLRcLOM8CTfnHF4lRjLf2"
    },
    "oTLYaHMOMibh3ZqOcmpcWDtSCKp1" : {
      "address" : “istanbul”,
      "cell_phone" : “none”,
      "email" : "ali@gmail.com”,
      "home_phone" : “none”,
      "name" : "Ali",
      "photoUrl" : "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/B/R/Y/m/P/e/blank-profile-hi.png",
      "userId" : "oTLYaHMOMibh3ZqOcmpcWDtSCKp1"
    }
  }
}
```

With this way everything works fine but **I don't know how to list user's all conversations at list like WhatsApp's Chats page.** I mean when user clicks the conversations item, **related** conversation will be open.
I'm sending private messages with code below:

```
public void sendMessageToFirebaseUser(final Context context, final ChatMessageModel chat, final String receiverFirebaseToken) {

        final String room_type_1 = chat.getSenderUid() + "_" + chat.getReceiverUid();
        final String room_type_2 = chat.getReceiverUid() + "_" + chat.getSenderUid();

        final DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        databaseReference.child(Constants.ARG_CHAT_ROOMS)
                .getRef()
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(room_type_1)) {
                            Log.e("aaa", "sendMessageToFirebaseUser: " + room_type_1 + " exists");
                            databaseReference.child(Constants.ARG_CHAT_ROOMS)
                                    .child(room_type_1)
                                    .push()
                                    .setValue(chat);
                        } else if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(room_type_2)) {
                            Log.e("aaa", "sendMessageToFirebaseUser: " + room_type_2 + " exists");
                            databaseReference.child(Constants.ARG_CHAT_ROOMS)
                                    .child(room_type_2)
                                    .push()
                                    .setValue(chat);
                        } else {
                            Log.e("aaa", "sendMessageToFirebaseUser: success");
                            databaseReference.child(Constants.ARG_CHAT_ROOMS)
                                    .child(room_type_1)
                                    .push()
                                    .setValue(chat);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
    }
```

Thank you for reading my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show a list of chat rooms for the current user, you should model your data to allow that. The easiest way to do this is to add a list of chat rooms for each user to your data model:

```
"userChatrooms" : {
  "nTAHqCTmLRcLOM8CTfnHF4lRjLf2" : {
    "nTAHqCTmLRcLOM8CTfnHF4lRjLf2_oTLYaHMOMibh3ZqOcmpcWDtSCKp1": true
  },
  "oTLYaHMOMibh3ZqOcmpcWDtSCKp1" : {
    "nTAHqCTmLRcLOM8CTfnHF4lRjLf2_oTLYaHMOMibh3ZqOcmpcWDtSCKp1": true
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you ! I figured to do what I want to see with this hint.